# Match different interviews by serial for data analysis (in R)

Tags: r, select, dataframe, match

In my data.frame I have data from 2 groups and 2 points in time. All interviews have serials by construction to match theirs data (each interview is one row). Consider the following MWE:

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c(12, 17, 13,15,20), B=c("MGT", "OXP", "SPX", "ABC", "XYA"), C=c(1,2,3,4,5), D=c("OXP", "MGT", "ABC", "XYA", "SPX")))

   A   B C   D
1 12 MGT 1 OXP
2 17 OXP 2 MGT
3 13 SPX 3 ABC
4 15 ABC 4 XYA
5 20 XYA 5 SPX
```

For example I need to add values of A and C for the same serial (B and D). But I cannot do this per row, because

```
if (df$B == df$D)
```

is never true. Maybe there is a command for "for each single df$B search the entire column of D for a match" and then "for this row of df$B add same row df$A with row df$C of the match".

Sometimes I only work on 1 variable for both serials. For example subtracting A in "for each serial df$B and the matching row in df$D".

Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest splitting data in two. And then join them.

Here's `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
df <- data.table(A=c(12, 17, 13,15,20), 
                      B=c("MGT", "OXP", "SPX", "ABC", "XYA"))
df2 <- data.table(C=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                      D=c("OXP", "MGT", "ABC", "XYA", "SPX"))

setkey(df,B);setkey(df2,D)
output <- df[df2]
output[,result:= ifelse(!is.na(A) & !is.na(C), A+C, NA)]
```

It also accounts for when there wouldn't be a match for serial number.

Base solution:

```
df$C <- df2$C[match(df$B, df2$D)]
df$result <- df$A + df$C
```

Can't really think of any simple solution that could do this within a single data frame...

Comment: Looks good! I need some time to understand this approach. Does this also work for operations on one single variable? I mean like, if I need to match the serials and subtract only column C by column C for each match.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I understood your question. You could update your question with an example + desired outcome.

Comment: For the second purpose I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523611/little-loop-foreach-match-and-rbind-in-r thx for help